# flex not working when vertically centering a textblock inside a column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using **Wordpress**, **Bridge Theme** and **WPBakery**.

With WPBakery I have created a `row` with two columns (equal width). On the left, is some custom HTML which takes up the vertical height, on the right is some text which does not.

I am trying to vertically align this text within the column, but not having much luck. I want this to be replicable, because I have this throughout my entire site (2 columns, one with a picture the other with a text).

This is what I'm currently trying in my div container element, which is the `row` div:

```
.row-custom-class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div      class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid  grid_section" style=' text-align:right;'><div class=" section_inner clearfix"><div class='section_inner_margin clearfix'><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html" >
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="testimonial-container">

                  <img src="img.png">

                  <p><span>Jane Doe.</span> <strong>Awesome Client.</strong></p>

                  <p><em>"sweet testimonial"</em></p>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></div><div class="text-container wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  text-container">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p style="text-align: center;">some text</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">some text some text some text some text some text</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">some text some text some text some text some text</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">some text some text some text some text some text</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><a class="maxbutton-1 maxbutton maxbutton-learn-about-transitional-coaching" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class='mb-text'>Learn About Coaching</span></a></strong></p>

        </div>
```

Should work but since it is a row, this probably does not happen as expected.

Could anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Can we see your HTML as well?

Comment: Yes, one second.

Comment: I built a codepen with your css + a border to show the entire div's space. It centers and left-justify's the text. Is this not what you want? https://codepen.io/tendermario/pen/WyvMPZ

Comment: thanks but no that isn't what I was wanting, the picture and texty text are in 2 different columns, your codepen puts them in the same

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want. When I run the given code it vertically aligns just fine. What is happening on your end that is unexpected?

Comment: it doesn't align vertically, you ran this code and it went just fine?

Comment: Yes. If you could replicate it in a code snippet or throw it in jsfiddle to replicate the issue and comment the link I can take a look

Comment: So it works fine in a codepen I use, but when applying it to my theme it does not. Maybe this is a conflict with the styling element? This is a automatic `row` generated by the theme, so maybe that means it does and automatic `display: inline-block`. Would that negate these changes?

Comment: I don't think `display: inline-block` would do it but automatic styles generated by the theme very well could.